# How do I programatically select an option when I'm defining them manually in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Surely there is a smart way to write this:

```
  %select{:name => "status", :id => "status"}
    - if params[:status].include? "Active"
      %option Either
      %option Inactive
      %option{:selected => :selected} Active
    - elsif params[:status].include? "Inactive"
      %option Either
      %option{:selected => :selected} Inactive
      %option Active
    - else
      %option{:selected => :selected} Either
      %option Inactive
      %option Active
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be:

```
  %select{:name => "status", :id => "status"}
    = options_for_select(["Either", "Active", "Inactive"], params[:status])
```